# Python calculating percentages from list

Tags: python, list

Hello i have a list that has the following information that is retrieved from a db

```
test_list_1 = ['01/01/2022:79.86','02/01/2022:65.86','03/01/2022:600.23','04/01/2022:179.26']
test_list_2 = ['01/01/2022:55.86','02/01/2022:25.75','03/01/2022:300.23']
```

I would like to be able to produce the following output from that:

```
# Output of test_list_1
01/01/2022 (79.86) => 02/01/2022 (65.86) => Percentage Diff (-17%)
01/01/2022 (79.86) => 03/01/2022 (600.23) => Percentage Diff (+651%)
01/01/2022 (79.86) => 04/01/2022 (179.26) => Percentage Diff (+124%)
02/01/2022 (65.86) => 03/01/2022 (600.23) => Percentage Diff (+811%)
02/01/2022 (65.86) => 04/01/2022 (179.26) => Percentage Diff (+172%)
03/01/2022 (600.23) => 04/01/2022 (179.26) => Percentage Diff (-70%)

# Output of test_list_2
01/01/2022 (55.86) => 02/01/2022 (25.75) => Percentage Diff (-53%)
01/01/2022 (55.86) => 03/01/2022 (300.23) => Percentage Diff (+437%)
02/01/2022 (25.75) => 03/01/2022 (300.23) => Percentage Diff (+1065%)
```

I am having a lot of trouble even trying to figure out the logic on how to do this. If some one can please assist me with just getting started with this that would be amazing.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think what you can do is: 1) Parse the strings inside the list to get percentages. 2) Append these percentages in a new list. 3) Then you can iterate the list and compute the differences you want. Maybe there is a Numpy function that does that sequential difference you're measuring.

Comment: I was just looking at numpy, but not able to figure out how to parse the data, in order for it to work using numpy. i did see it has a function called pct_chnage, but not understanding how to use it in my case.

Comment: How much of your code is working and where do you get stuck? Like, have you figured out how to split the strings? Or are you stuck on the logic of stepping through the combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that relies on the powerful `itertools` module to first generate combinations.

Applied here on `test_list1`.

Just make a function of that to apply to any list in argument.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def pdiff(src: float, dst: float) -> float:
    return (dst-src)/src*100

combs = [(x,y) for x,y in combinations(test_list_1, 2)]
for x, y in combs:
    dtx, percentx = x.split(":")
    dty, percenty = y.split(":")
    print(f"{dtx} ({percentx}) => {dty} ({percenty}) => Percentage Diff ({pdiff(float(percentx), float(percenty)): .2f}%)")
```

Comment: You should really get rid of `combs`, and just do `for x, y in combinations(test_list_1, 2):`; converting it to a `list` first (and pointlessly inefficiently with a no-op listcomp rather than just calling `list` on it) increases peak memory requirements significantly and adds latency to generate all the combinations up front, when directly iterating the `combinations` object has neither issue. You'd also save a decent amount of work for larger inputs by parsing `test_list_1` up front (so you only split the strings and convert to `float` once per input item, not twice per output combination).

Answer (score 2):

You have two major hurdles to get from the starting point to the paired off values you need:

1. Parsing the strings to useful data
2. Matching up the parsed data to perform your computations

Parsing is fairly simple:

```
parsed_list_1 = []
for s in test_list_1:
    date, sep, price = s.partition(':')
    # Optionally test "if sep:" and raise an error if the data didn't have the expected colon in it
    parsed_list_1.append((date, float(price))  # Store a tuple of the date string and parsed prices
```

Once you've got a parsed `list` of date-price `tuple`s, since your data is already in sorted order, you can [use `itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) (with `import itertools` at the top of the file) to pair up each date's data with each subsequent date, e.g.:

```
for (start_date, start_price), (end_date, end_price) in itertools.combinations(parsed_list_1, 2):
    # Do stuff with each pair of dates and associated prices
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZHdSsQwEIXv@xTDepEUSu1mddWCz@CFl7IssZ26gWwSklHcp6/5KeuuYCllOMmc78zUnehgzWae1dFZT6AIPVmrQ1URBtprFT9reIY31q1v4ys6IfqHp/ZxyxrWibO0vV@kza/Uda3YJO3urK1jq9iyXVU56QOOF4BdNVkPAZSBC3RfQXxGSdhAQNeA82rAeD@00YEUKWs461md793Ai0uK1PqUXWClptTXr0CaEbxUAWMF6H2ExTM6YHKXMKrRMIKD/MIs4rfDgXCEwWprUipFmXEVvJXOoRk5LwknbSXxHLGu65TnlayPRKBPpxHsGYgQyCvzkWMVyzJa3HzaAw8Ux9svg@e62DbAI3A5SFWRS8Dl57WDPb4rI9MqAr8K3ICoy05jn6H/MMX6L2SefwA)

I'm leaving it up to you how to compute the percentage difference, adapt the code to work with multiple input `list`s without writing the same code twice, format your output, and (if necessary) how to handle sorting the data if it's not guaranteed to be in order by date already, but this is 80% of the work. You could solve it without `itertools.combinations` with carefully constructed nested `for` loops, e.g.

```
for i, (start_date, start_price) in enumerate(parsed_list_1, 1):
    for end_date, end_price in parsed_list_1[i:]:
        # Do stuff with each pair of dates and associated prices
```

but it's slower, more verbose, and frankly less clear. The `itertools` module is friggin' magic; use it when you can.

Comment: This is the best answer - should be accepted. +1 for the time analysis.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the desired output through a relatively simple set of lists manipulations. Here is my solution for the first list (it is exactly the same for the second).

```
test_list_1 =['01/01/2022:79.86','02/01/2022:65.86','03/01/2022:600.23','04/01/2022:179.26']

test_list_1 = [el.split(':') for el in test_list_1]

for index, value in enumerate(test_list_1):
  for next_index, next_value in enumerate(test_list_1[index+1:]):
    v = 100*(float(next_value[1]) - float(value[1]))/float(value[1])
    print(f"{value[0]} ({value[1]}) => {next_value[0]} ({next_value[1]}) => Percentage Diff ({int(v)})%")
```

Here I am assuming the list elements are strings and you are interested only in printing the output as you reported it.

Hope this helps, bless!

Answer (score 0):

Different solution:

```
lst = ['01/01/2022:79.86','02/01/2022:65.86','03/01/2022:600.23','04/01/2022:179.26']


def pairings(pool):
    for i, m in enumerate(pool):
        for n in pool[i+1:]:
            yield (m, n)

new_list = list(pairings(lst))

for i,j in new_list:
    diff = int((float(j.split(":", 1)[1]) - float(i.split(":", 1)[1]))/float(i.split(":", 1)[1])*100)
    print(i + " => " + j + " => Percentage Diff " + str(diff) + "%")
```

Comment: `pairings` can save a tiny amount of work by changing `enumerate(pool)` to `enumerate(pool, 1)`, allowing `pool[i+1:]` to become `pool[i:]`. Basically lets the optimized tool (`enumerate`) directly produce the indices you need, rather than repeatedly applying a small fix with Python level code. There's no reason to do `new_list = list(pairings(lst))` though; you could just iterate `for i, j in pairings(lst):` and get some benefit from the lazy generator function you wrote.